# Word for the Way a Culture or Group Feeds Itself

Tags: single-word-requests

Does there exist a word that collectively refers to the ways cultures get their food? (i.e. agriculture, hunter-gatherer society) I can't find any words relating to this concept in the way that I need

Example Sentence: 'A phoresite is more likely to become pastoral than find some other __________'

Comment: What would be wrong with 'food source' or 'source of food'? How is it helpful to use 'phoresite' as an example, instead of anything real? Come to that, how is 'more likely to become pastoral…' helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a singular word, I would say that, based on your example sentence, 'form of sustenance' or 'form of nourishment' would work well. Both refer to a form of food and are not specific as to what that food is.